# numpy.vectorize: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble when using np.vectorize in my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

length = 1000

evens = np.array([np.arange(0, length*2, 2)])
odds = np.array([np.arange(1, length*2, 2)])

zeroes = np.array([np.resize([[0]], length)])
ones = np.array([np.resize([[1]], length)])

evens_data = np.concatenate((evens.T, zeroes.T), axis=1)
odds_data = np.concatenate((odds.T, ones.T), axis=1)

data = np.array(np.append(evens_data, odds_data)).reshape(length*2, 2)
np.random.shuffle(data)
X = np.array(data[:,0], dtype=np.uint8).reshape(length*2,1)
y = data[:,1]

###
### IF I COMMENT FROM HERE
###
print(f'1 X.dtype: {X.dtype} X[0].dtype: {X[0].dtype} and X.shape {X.shape} and X[0].shape {X[0].shape}')
X = tobinstr(X)
print(f'2 X.dtype: {X.dtype} X[0].dtype: {X[0].dtype} and X.shape {X.shape} and X[0].shape {X[0].shape}')
X = tobits(X)
print(f'3 X.dtype: {X.dtype} X[0].dtype: {X[0].dtype} and X.shape {X.shape} and X[0].shape {X[0].shape} and X[0][0].shape {X[0][0].shape}')
X = X[:,0]
print(f'4 X.dtype: {X.dtype} X[0].dtype: {X[0].dtype} and X.shape {X.shape} and X[0].shape {X[0].shape}')
###
### TO HERE, the code works fine
###

KNeighborsClassifier(3).fit(X, y) 

# The line above fails with error "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"
# Caused by: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

And here's the output:

```
1 X.dtype: uint8 X[0].dtype: uint8 and X.shape (2000, 1) and X[0].shape (1,)
2 X.dtype: <U16 X[0].dtype: <U16 and X.shape (2000, 1) and X[0].shape (1,)
3 X.dtype: object X[0].dtype: object and X.shape (2000, 1) and X[0].shape (1,) and X[0][0].shape (16,)
4 X.dtype: object X[0].dtype: uint8 and X.shape (2000,) and X[0].shape (16,)
```

How do I turn X into a shape of (2000,16)?

Comment: Show the full traceback, and give us information on how `X` differs between the working and the error case. - array shape, and dtype, and a sample of the values.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have wasted my time, and instead waited for the info that I requested, but.  `X` before is a (n,1) array of `uint8` dtype.  After the conversion it is a (n,) array of object dtype, where the elements are (16,) arrays with 0/1 values.  I haven't read the docs for this `fit`, but is that an allowable input?  When you hit the error, did you go back and reread those docs?

Comment: I bet the `fit` is trying to make a numeric (float or int) array from the `X`.  `np.array(X, dtype=int)` produces this error message.  `np.stack(X)` may work, producing a (n,16) int dtype array.  I don't know if that's what `fit` needs or not.